# How to bookmark/mark lines in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I work on a large project with lots of files. How can I bookmark or mark a specific file and a line within it?

Thanks.

Comment: See interesting solutions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473207/how-to-bookmark-code-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK - you can't. You can access any method quickly by assigning the keyboard shortcut to jump bar's method list.