# How do you find all references to a method or property in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

If you have a method, e.g., `loadMediaImages` in a `.h` file, how do you find all references to that method in the project? In **Visual Studio** there is a "Find All References" option on the content menu when you highlight and click the method name. Anything similar in **Xcode**?

Comment: From the answers it seems this functionality does not exist in XCode 4. I have submitted an Enhancement request to Apple support.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [Find method references in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145045/find-method-references-in-xcode), and though this one was posted first, the other has received more views and better answers so this one should probably be closed (though +1 anyway). Note that, despite the title, the question (and my answer) include properties.

Answer (score 5):

Using the "Search Navigator" it's possible to search for symbol references within a project or workspace. Click on the little magnifying glass icon in the search box to "Show Find Options", and then select the Style: Symbol References.

[image: Search Navigator with find options]

*Note: This is in Xcode 4.6, but may have been present in earlier versions.*

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for similar option. I do not know why Xcode did not included that.
But there is a work around I use until Apple give that option in Xcode.

Try this in the source code (.m) file,

```
Select the symbol, right click -> Refactor -> Rename 
-> Give a name whatever you wish, then press Preview.
```

Now you can see all the references. You can `Cancel`/do not rename it. :)

Or press `Cmd + Shift + F`, and choose optons Find > References > Matching or Containing. But it will search all text with similar name. Not elegant like Refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

***Find selected symbol in workspace*** is what you need

- right click on the method/property -> Find -> Find selected symbol in workspace
- focus the property/method and press ⇧ + ⌃ + ⌘ + F (or you can have a custom one)

Does basically the same search as Refactor -> Rename does

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, Xcode 4 (not sure about previous versions) does not support a Find All References search. You can perform a text search within the entire project by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Find in Workspace in the Edit menu), but this does not find exact "references", just matching text. You're best bet is using the Refactoring menu, as talked about in [Finding all references of a variable or a method in Xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457190/finding-all-references-of-a-variable-or-a-method-in-xcode4), but it is not very clean and requires more work than it should.