# Find method references in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ide

Is there a way in Xcode to find all the places where a method or property has been been called?

In Eclipse, for example, you can right-click a method and select *Find references*. Is there anything similar in Xcode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you find all references to a method or property in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751740/how-do-you-find-all-references-to-a-method-or-property-in-xcode)

Comment: @BjörnLarsson Given the number of votes on this question and its answers, and the overall better quality of the answers, the vote should be to close it in the other direction, as a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I respectfully disagree. Given that both questions are equal in quality, the one posted first should have priority. Would it be possible to move answers and karma to that question?

Comment: My rationale is that a user shouldn't loose Internet points just because someone else posted the same thing a month later.

Comment: @BjörnLarsson Both questions are not of equal quality, and age is the least important metric to consider when determining duplicate direction. Considering that 'quality' is also something of a subjective thing, we should rely next on some other _objective_ metrics: number of answers, number of views, score of question, general score of answers, etc. This question handily beats the other in all metrics. As for age, they were posted 1 month apart, _over ten years ago_. For all practical purposes, they are the essentially the exact same "age".

Comment: @BjörnLarsson I'm also not sure what you mean by losing reputation. Closed questions don't deprive anyone of reputation.

Answer (score 270):

1. Select the method you're interested in, or position the text cursor within it.
2. Open the "Related Files" menu via the icon at the top-left of the Editor. (It's the button immediately to the left of the back button).
3. Go to the "Callers" submenu for a list of all methods that call the selected method, and click any of them to jump to that file and method.

In pictures...

[image: Screenshot of steps 1 and 2 above.]

[image: Screenshot of step 3 above]

A couple of notes:

- You can do this for properties too.
- Note that when you select a calling method from the Callers menu to jump to where your method was called, Xcode highlights only the *first* call. Each calling method will only show up in the 'Callers' list once, even if it contains many calls to your method. So if you're trying to make some change at every place in your application where a method is called, be careful not to miss some in places where a calling method contains two calls to the method you're interested in.

Comment: The default shortcut for bringing up the menu in `^1` so I'm usually able to press `^1, c, enter` to bring up the list.

Comment: This finds all Callers of the method and the parent implementations.  Is there a way to find Callers of *only* this implementation?

Comment: @DanielKaplan I would guess not, since in at least some cases the compiler won't have any way of knowing which implementation is to be called.

Comment: My method is called `init`, and this brings up any method named `init` as well. Not so smart...

Comment: This is a good way, but sometimes xcode (I currently have 12.5) bugs out and this menu "Related files" only shows "Recent files" and "Locally Modified Files". In that case restart Xcode or use Command+shift+A

Answer (score 37):

Yes, open the Assistant editor and instead of Counterparts select Callers.

[image]

Comment: You don't *have* to use the split editor for this, although it may be convenient if you're going to be editing lots of the calling methods in quick succession. See my answer.

Answer (score 28):

Select function, press cmd-shift-A, "Callers"

[image]

Comment: Analogous keyboard shortcut (that shows results in the Find Navigator panel instead of a temporary popup): `[cmd]+[ctrl]+[shift]+[h]`

Answer (score 18):

As of XCode 4.5 you can click on "Show find options" within the search field of the Search Navigator. There you can specify "Symbol References"

[image]

Comment: This is a slight improvement over a bare search, but it returns *all* references, not just the particular one you're looking for. For instance, if you have a class with a "height" property, searching for symbol references on your height property will return references to all kinds of other height properties you used, so you still have to sift through the results to find the ones you want. For a hack that works fairly nicely see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5457479/850721

Answer (score 7):

Place the insertion point in a method invocation or declaration and choose Find > Find Selected Symbol In Project.  For multipart selectors this will only highlight the first part but searching does seem to work relatively reliably.  You can also use Find Call Hierarchy which highlights the entire line instead.

The corresponding contextual menu item (Find Selected Symbol in Workspace) also works, but it's a bit trickier to make work properly.  Make sure no text gets selected otherwise it'll search for the selected word rather than the entire selector.  To do so, you can click with the left mouse button prior to clicking with the right mouse button (or Control-clicking) in the same location.  There's no such issue with the contextual Find Call Hierarchy.

Comment: its also very useful to have a keyboard shortcut for the same, debugging gets so much quicker

Answer (score -14):

With xcode 4 you can now right click on references and select "jump to definition."

Comment: That answers the opposite question.