# Xcode 5 plugins for C++ development

Tags: c++, macos, development-environment

After switching from Visual Studio 2012 with latest Visual Assist to XCode 5 for C++ development I feel very unhandy. I cannot find the comfort of doing such things:

- renaming
- finding usages
- switching back and forth between definition and declaration
- changing function signature
- inserting code snippets such as `#ifndef A #define A /*here come header file*/ #endif`

But I am sure that there are lot of C++ developer on Mac and of course there should be handy tools for them. Please advice what I need to install. What is the standard arsenal of C++ developer on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch back and forth between definition and declaration with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+Click on a function name.

You create Code snippets by dragging selected code to the right pane with snippets.
Here's better explanation: http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/

Unfortunatelly renaming only works with `ObjC` and `C`.

I didn't use `VS` so I don't know if my suggestions are what You've asked.

Comment: @Narek: ⌘+Click usually works. The catch is that Xcode seems to have a very hard time indexing C++ projects and will occasionally just choke. Try restarting the project, wait for a minute to give Xcode a chance to reindex the project and then try again.
P.S. - Just to be sure... Are you sure the corresponding cpp/h file is properly included in the project?

Comment: @Mattia yes they are included correctly. What about finding usages? Is there any way?

Comment: @Narek Could You explain, what do You mean by "finding usages"? I don't know VS...

Comment: @Narek: Yes, there's a similar feature in Xcode where you can get a list of a method/function's callers and callees. This answer on SO explains the details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145045/find-method-references-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a lot.

However, if you have to use Xcode, start here with a plugin manager: 
http://alcatraz.io/

Personally I use the autocomplete plugin and the vim emulation to make my life better.  Both installable via alcatraz.

Unfortunately the C++ refactoring totally sucks.  I have Visual Studio installed via parallels and I'm popping back to that to do anything automated.

Top tip: Use Command-Shift-O for finding a file.

This also looks interesting (and is also installable via alcatraz): 
http://codepilot.cc/