# Remove code with Xcode search

Tags: xcode, xcode4, automatic-ref-counting

I just went over to the ARC in my iPhone/iPad app and it works great, but I have this code in the files that are shared with other projects `#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)`.

For example:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
    [logInView release];
#endif

    logInView = nil;
}
```

And my question is: Can I remove all this code by any search function in XCode or must I do it for hand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could regex with something like:

`#[\s]*if[\s]*!__has_feature\(objc_arc\)[\s\S]*?(#[\s]*endif)`

if you include any more space in there, then you would want to add symbols for those, I accounted for :

```
#    if
#    endif
```

but not

```
 __has_feature (  objc_arc  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can, Highlight what you want to change and click refactor -> rename. In the rename view, you can change it to whatever you like.

[image: Here]

This question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457190/finding-all-references-of-a-variable-or-a-method-in-xcode4). A google search can be your best friend :)